# How hyperledger Fabric cost storage of machine?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am using hyperledger Fabric and Composer starting my blockchain, and I make 17000+ transactions, but it cost 1.8GB in peer container(~100KB/transaction).I have computed the storage of one transaction which may only cost 1KB+. So my question is how fabric save the data in ledger?
I have used the rest-api to find my records, like:

```
[
  {
    "$class": "org.chembeango.io.Compound",
    "compoundId": "870-77-9",
    "name": "3-acetyloxy-4-(trimethylazaniumyl)butanoate",
    "smiles": "CC(=O)OC(CC(=O)[O-])C[N+](C)(C)C",
    "cas": "870-77-9",
    "source": "pubchem",
    "location": "http://192.168.11.111:9200/compounds",
    "owner": "resource:org.chembeango.io.CompoundParticipant#cp1@email.com"
  },
  {
    "$class": "org.chembeango.io.Compound",
    "compoundId": "pubchem-2",
    "name": "(2-acetyloxy-3-carboxypropyl)-trimethylazanium",
    "smiles": "CC(=O)OC(CC(=O)O)C[N+](C)(C)C",
    "cas": "pubchem-2",
    "source": "pubchem",
    "location": "http://192.168.11.111:9200/compounds",
    "owner": "resource:org.chembeango.io.CompoundParticipant#cp1@email.com"
  },
...
```

Each transaction may create several events, but I don't think this can cost such large storage per transaction.

My channel's block configure is:

```
BatchTimeout: 2s

BatchSize:
    MaxMessageCount: 10
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
```

and I create 1 transaction in each block, is each of the blocks has its minimun size?

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem, I add query function in my logic.js,like

```
const validateActions = await query('selectAllValidateActions');
```

and I tailed the blockfiles and find the logs are:

```
,Asset:org.chembeango.io.ValidateAction96�
3
,Asset:org.chembeango.io.ValidateAction96�
3
,Asset:org.chembeango.io.ValidateAction96�
3
,Asset:org.chembeango.io.ValidateAction96�
3
,Asset:org.chembeango.io.ValidateAction96�
3
,Asset:org.chembeango.io.ValidateAction96�
3
,Asset:org.chembeango.io.ValidateAction96�
3
,Asset:org.chembeango.io.ValidateAction96�
3
,Asset:org.chembeango.io.ValidateAction96�
3
,Asset:org.chembeango.io.ValidateAction96�
...
```

maybe the the transaction logs all my query result to the Ledger.
So the ledger saved a lot of useless info.
But why composer query result might saved to the ledger?